# Creating a EntityManagerFactory in Hibernate in OSGi

Tags: hibernate, jpa, osgi

I'm in the process of getting Hibernate to work with OSGi, so the base for this project is `org.hibernate.osgi`.

I've created the following *persistence.xml*:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="DemoUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" />

            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="org.hibernate.FlushMode" value="commit" />
            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And I try to access it with the following code:

```
    BundleContext context = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass()).getBundleContext();
    ServiceReference serviceReference = context.getServiceReference(PersistenceProvider.class.getName());
    PersistenceProvider persistenceProvider = (PersistenceProvider) context.getService(serviceReference);
    EntityManagerFactory emf = persistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory("DemoUnit", null);
```

Afterwards, the `EntityManagerFactory` is null. There is no exception, no log, no nothing.

What I know:

- the plug-in reads the *persistence.xml*, and it fails if it's malformed
- the plug-in can access the `org.h2.Driver`, since I can import it
- some sources state to use Log4J and something like `Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ALL)` to get an exception; for me there are no changes if I add the line

Can somebody help me find the source of the problem?

Comment: Once long time ago I wrote some notes about configuring JPA in the OSGi environment https://gusto77.wordpress.com/2013/03/27/simple-working-jpa-project-in-osgi-environment/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is really simple: the provider is wrong (or obsolete?). Would have been way easier to find if Hibernate printed logs:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

PersistenceProvider is located in a different bundle than your persistence classes and persistence.xml. So it can not see these.

It might help to set the ContextClassLoader to the classloader of your bundle.

The better way to use hibernate is to use Aries JPA in the middle. It creates the EntityManagerFactory for you in an OSGi safe way and provides the EMF as an OSGi service.

See the [Aries JPA examples](https://github.com/apache/aries-jpa/tree/master/examples).

There is also support for creating the DataSource as a service from a config using [pax-jdbc-config](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXJDBC/Create+DataSource+from+config).